# Resolving function name conflicts by using static

Tags: c

Say we have a library that defines the following internally used function `skip_comments`, that is used only by the translation unit it is defined in

```c
void skip_comments(...)
{
}

void another_function()
{
    skip_comments(...) //calls the above function  --- (1)
}
```

Now this library is used by another process which also has a function with the same name `skip_comments`.

This will cause a function name conflict between the library function vs the function defined in the process. So at the point `(1)` I might expect it to call the process's function instead of the library function which clearly is a bug.

As a possible fix, I made the `skip_comment` function `static` and now the bug seems to be fixed. But I'm not sure if this is a proper fix

My question is, would defining the `skip_comment` as `static` ensure that at `(1)` such a name conflict will not occur? ie.

```c
static void skip_comments(...)
{
}

void another_function()
{
    skip_comments(...) // will it always call the internal function?
}
```

Or the only solution is to make sure we define a unique name for functions such as adding prefixes?

Comment: Make every function in every module that is not exposed in a header static — so it cannot be accessed outside its module by accident. Ditto for file scope (global) variables.  Limit the scope of functions whenever possible. This reduces the chance for name conflicts. It actually makes it easier to modify code; if a function is static, you don't usually need to look elsewhere for uses of the function (the exception being if you return a pointer to the function somewhere). Note that functions must be declared before they are used; only functions declared in headers can be used outside their TU.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a function as `static` means that it will only be accessible by the translation unit where it is declared. (Translation unit meaning the .c file and all .h files included by that .c file.)

So yes, declaring it as `static` will solve your name conflicts. Given that you do this consistently everywhere and not just in one file.

However, it is good practice to prefix all identifiers based on the module where they belong, so that is perhaps the best solution regardless.

Comment: Re “means that it will only be accessible by the translation unit where it is declared”: It means this instance of the name is only visible in the translation unit and will not be linked to a different instance of the function. The function can still be accessed from other translation units by using its address.